# Find the difference of days between 2 timestamps in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have 2 columns, date opened and date closed which have timestamps for an excel sheet with thousands of rows.

```
         A                       B  
 1    Date Opened             Date Closed
 2  07/16/2019 04:19 PM     07/24/2019 11:39 AM
```

**Issue**:

1. If I try `Days360(A2,B2)` I get ####### as output. On taking cursor over the cell of Days360(A2,B2) I get message, days too large value or negative hence shown as ####
2. Same problem of ###### with Datedif.
3. `=month(B2) & '/' day(B2) & '/' & year(B2)` also does not work

Is there any way to calculate number of days between 2 timestamps?

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? `=Days360(A2,B2)` seems to work fine for me. *I am currently using Excel 2016*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=MONTH(B2) & "/" & DAY(B2) & "/" & YEAR(B2)
```

This works. Apparently you need double quotes and not single quote around /.

Comment: Your original code was missing an `&` between `"/"` and `day(b2)`